# Xcode and Eigen Library for linear algebra

Tags: xcode, eigen

Im trying to use the [Eigen library](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) in Xcode. So far i have installed the library with homebrew into `/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.1/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense` and use it within my project with the absolute path like so:

```
#include "/usr/local/Cellar/eigen/3.2.1/include/eigen3/Eigen/Dense"
```

The project is shared via git, thus the absolute path is not working for everyone contributing to this project. Is it somehow possible to replace the absolute path with `#include <Eigen/Dense>` so Xcode will automatically look up in the correct path? Can i include the path to these libraries?

Comment: you can set search paths in the preferences (only the include/header search path is relevant to eigen, since it's all templates)